# How is a channel's output-buffer content deleted without writing it to the channel?

Tags: tcl

I don't know much about PHP or Tcl; but I am trying to learn both concurrently.
In PHP, I read that every script should start with `ob_start` and, therefore, have been using the following.

```
ob_start(NULL, 0, PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_STDFLAGS);
echo header('Content-Length: '.ob_get_length());
ob_end_flush();
ob_end_clean();
```

In Tcl channels, I see that the options of `-buffering full` and `-buffersize` take care of `ob_start()` and `chan flush` is analogous to `ob_end_flush()` and `chan pending output` returns the number of bytes written to the output buffer but not yet written out.

I've been looking at my two texts on Tcl and the Tcl manual web page for [channels](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/chan.html) and I can't find a method of just clearing the channel output buffer without writing it.

If data is being written to a channel set to `-buffering full` and an error is caught/trapped is it possible to empty the buffer and not write it to the channel?

It though perhaps that could use `chan seek` to set the position back to start similar to setting a pointer back to the beginning of a segment of RAM but the pipe example doesn't appear to create a channel that supports seeking.

```
lassign [chan pipe] rchan wchan
chan configure $rchan -buffering line -blocking 0 -translation crlf
chan configure $wchan -buffering full -blocking 0 -translation crlf

chan puts $wchan "This is the full messsage which shall attempt to truncate."
chan puts stdout "wchan pending: [chan pending output $wchan]"
chan puts stdout "wchan tell: [chan tell $wchan]"
# => -1 Thus, channel does not support seeking.

#chan seek $wchan 5 start
# => Errors invalid seek

chan flush $wchan
chan puts stdout [chan gets $rchan]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to only output text written to a channel if no error happens in the middle of writing?

One way is to use a [variable channel](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/md/tcllib/files/modules/virtchannel_base/tcllib_variable.md) from [tcllib](https://www.tcl.tk/software/tcllib/); everything written to the channel is stored in a variable, which can then be written out to the real target on successful completion of whatever you're trying to do.

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh
package require tcl::chan::variable

proc main {} {
    variable output
    set output ""
    set outputchan [::tcl::chan::variable output]
    try {
        puts $outputchan "Some text"

        error "This is an error"

        # Won't get written if an error is raised
        chan flush $outputchan
        puts -nonewline $output
    } on error {errMsg errOptions} {
        # Report error if you want
    } finally {
        chan close $outputchan
    }
}
main
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Tcl provides the functionality you are looking for.  It's assumed that if you send something to a channel then it should always be written out.